# Save image path in database issue

Tags: database, database-design, web-applications

When user upload image I resize that image in 3 different sizes. I can't decide what is better option:

**1)** Save image path in one column in database like: `User9876/ImageName` and extension in another column. When I get user profile data from database I have business object with three properties for different image size. And in code I fill this properties by adding extension to image path from database like:

```
User9876/ImageName_Original.jpg
User9876/ImageName_Small.jpg
User9876/ImageName_Smallest.jpg
```

**2)** Or it is better to have three columns in database for each size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of recommendations:

1. Don't store the extension separately, unless you plan on querying for particular extensions. Just adds more complexity for no real gain.
2. I would store the image size code as an id in your images table. This way you can update/edit image codes without having to run an update statement on your entire table.

   create table image (
       `id` int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment,
       `path` varchar(255) not null,
       `size_code_id` smallint(3) not null,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   )Engine=MyISAM Default Charset=utf8;

Example row:

```
1 | user9876/imagename_og.jpg | 1
2 | user9876/imagename_me.jpg | 2
3 | user9876/imagename_sm.jpg | 3
```

This design will allow you to query for the 'small' image without having to parse the filename, yet you can still make the distinction of a small image from medium and original images on the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question can be found by asking yourself another question: what is going to happen if you later choose to have not three, but four different image sizes? Clearly, the solution which does not require you to reorganize your entire database is better.